# git cannot push to existing repo

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repo energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400, but I have problem in push the file to this repo

```
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git remote add origin https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git
error: remote origin already exists.
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git branch -M main
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git.'
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git remote remove origin
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git remote add origin https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git branch -M main
(base) esp32@Arthurs-Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git'
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git'
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git pull --rebase
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git/' not found
(base) Mac-Pro energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400 % git push
error: src refspec refs/heads/main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/energys_arduino_max485_mqtt_autoconnect_ec400.git'
```

why I cannot push to GitHub??

Comment: Did you `commit`ed something at that branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to upload all of your code at once to the empty repo you've made on github's site. It also seems you've already run `git init`

You need to first commit all of your changes with `git add .` then `git commit -m "comment you choose"` so that you have something to push. It's possible that you've made a new branch, you don't need a branch in this situation.

> `git add .`
>
> `git commit -m "first commit"`
>
> `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`
>
> `git push`

Comment: checkout this git tutorial, it really helped me when I was starting out https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Comment: (base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git add .
(base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git commit -m "update"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
(base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git checkout main
error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
(base) Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect %

Comment: The checkout main have error?

Comment: I use a new repo and new folder also fail. omg

Comment: @Samuel "nothing to commit, working tree clean" -> You should have something to commit before doing anything.

Comment: okay sorry about suggesting you switch branches. I changed my answer to reflect that. if you're using a new folder, start with `git init` in your terminal. then do `git add .` `git commit -m "first commit"` `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git` then `git push`

Comment: -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git add .             
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git commit -m "update"
[master 6c6fb9f] update
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 readme
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git add .

Comment: -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git commit -m "first commit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git remote add origin https://github.com/SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git
error: remote origin already exists.
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git/' not found
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect %

Comment: I try to add a readme file in the folder but still cannot push to git. Is there have any way to push to git?

Comment: you don't need to continuously add a remote. that's just like a one time thing that sets up your connection to your repo. from this point, do this: 1) `git add .` 2) `git commit -m "first commit"` 3)`git push origin`

Comment: @Samuel Did you created the repository? I can't find it, this means whether you set it as private, or you didn't create it. Create it on the website if you didn't create a repository.

Comment: (base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git push origin
remote: Permission to SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git denied to XiotSamuel.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: @Geno Chen I create a new one 485_mqtt_autoconnect repo.

Comment: @Samuel OK, then what is your GitHub account, "SamuelXiot" or "XiotSamuel"? and what is the account **stored in the ... maybe "keyring"? for authenticating to GitHub from your computer**?

Comment: -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git config --global user.name SamuelXiot
-Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git push origin                         
remote: Permission to SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git denied to XiotSamuel.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: tried to change the username but still using the wrong one. anyway to correct it?

Comment: @Samuel No, the `git config --global user.name` just used for making a commit, not for authenticating to Git services.

Comment: where is the file/setting for authenticating git service?

Comment: @Samuel Maybe the "Git Credential Helper", maybe the system "keyring". I don't use a macOS computer so I am not sure what the latter is the most important one.

Comment: brew install --cask git-credential-manager-core. I found this cmd in the git.doc. May be there have some setting there...  =.=""

Comment: I found it. Need to delete all credentials first then gen a new token at git and relogin

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution, I need to update the GitHub account in Mac first.

Need to delete all account credential

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]
```

create a PAT

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

then update the git login in terminal

(base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect % git push origin
Username for 'https://github.com': SamuelXiot
Password for 'https://SamuelXiot@github.com':
Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 3.22 KiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To https://github.com/SamuelXiot/485_mqtt_autoconnect.git

- [new branch]      master -> master
  (base) -Mac-Pro 485_mqtt_autoconnect %

then normal again.

thanks all for the help.

Comment: Just as a note ssh (not https) is as far as I know always the preferred method for pushing and pulling from github - perhaps at this point you want to leave well enough alone though.